# on-the-fly copy of an audio cd using "on-board" programs?

Tags: windows-7

I have two CDROM drives in my personal computer

```
D: CDROM/DVD Reader
E: CDROM/DVD Writer
```

A lot of external programs (e.g. Nero or CD-Burner) can directly copy an audio-cd in CDROM drive D: to another empty cd in CDROM drive E:. I think they call it an "on-the-fly" copy.

I am wondering if  the same thing is possible by using the Windows7 on-board programs <s>(create a direct 1:1 clone)</s>.

**EDIT:** The Windows7 Media Player can copy the tracks from an audio-cd in Drive D: to the hard disk. Afterwards I can burn these tracks from the hard disk to CDROM Drive E:. But that's very time consuming and wastes a lot of space on the harddrive.

**EDIT:** It doesn't need to be an *exact* 1:1 clone. I only want a "standard" CD-Player to play the music.

**ACCEPTED**: (from a comment by Molly) ... for 'on the fly' you do need a 3rd party program ...

Comment: ripping with WMP and burning the results does not guarantee a 1:1 clone.  if you go with that process, make sure it's ripping uncompressed tracks, or you'll be making lossy copies.

Comment: Hey answerers... is there a Windows 7 built-in tool to rip .iso files? If so that would solve it because you can burn .iso files natively now.

Comment: @Nathaniel - no, it wouldn't solve it because Vokuhila-Oliba is looking for 'disk copy on the fly' (from D: to E:). and that's not possible with Windows 7 "on-board" programs. whether as ISO or as ripped WAV files, either way it will be buffered on the hard drive. maybe 'time consuming' but temporarily copying up to 700 MB to the HDD isn't really wasting "a lot of space on the harddrive".

Comment: Ah, right. I'm not sure that that was there when I commented, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A lot of external programs (e.g. Nero
>   or CD-Burner) can directly copy an
>   audio-cd in CDROM drive D: to another
>   empty cd in CDROM drive E:
>
> I am wondering if it is somehow
>   possible to create a direct 1:1 clone
>   of an audio CD using the Windows7
>   on-board programs.

No, that's not possible.

However, since you asking about Audio CDs, my favorite tool is **[Exact Audio Copy](http://www.exactaudiocopy.de/)** (aka EAC), there is no better software when it comes to ripping audio CDs ... and it's absolutely free.

[image]

For burning audio CDsIi recommend another freebie called **[Burrrn](http://www.burrrn.net/?page_id=4)**:

> Burrrn is a little tool for creating
>   audio CDs with CD-Text from various
>   audio files. Supported formats are:
>   wav, mp3, mpc, ogg, aac, mp4, ape,
>   flac, ofr, wv, tta, m3u, pls and fpl
>   playlists and cue sheets.

[image]

Now, this may not be the fastest method, but i consider myself an audiophile and i'm only interested in quality. If you want just speed, sure most DVD writing programs can do the job faster by copying "on the fly".

Comment: is EAC not postcard-ware anymore? when did that change?

Comment: EAC is the best ripper for quality, but it (used to be anyway) a PITA to setup.

Comment: @~quack - i think it changed with version 0.99 but even before that the postcard was a voluntary affair, not mandatory.

Comment: @Iain  - the setup wizard now is rather straight forward if you opt for the 'easy way out' ... if you want in-depth tutorials, check the forums at hydrogenaudio.org

Comment: If I understood the documentation right then EAC cannot do on-the-fly copies.

Comment: @Vokuhila-Oliba - of course not, EAC is a highly specialized audio track ripper, it's not made for 'copying' discs ... it's about the content and preserving the best possible quality. you want 'on the fly', you can use any regular DVD burning soft, such as the one you picked (InfraRecorder). your question was: Is it possible with on-board programs, and the answer is no.

Comment: @Molly: Sorry, when I initially asked the question I did not know about the right terms to use. Now I now better. What I'm actually looking for is "on-the-fly" copy with "on-board" programs.

Comment: @Vokuhila-Oliba - and this is NOT possible, for 'on the fly' you do need a 3rd party program, but you found one with InfraRecorder already. :)

Comment: you're more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This is not available using the built-in programs of Windows 7 - however I would highly recommend [CDBurnerXP](http://www.cdburnerxp.se). It is also available on [Ninite](http://www.ninite.com) (for very easy installation).

Simply click `Audio CD` on the first screen then click `File > Copy Audio Disc`; it should do a straight copy from one disk to another.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out `File > Copy Audio Disc`! CDBurnerXP is quite OK. But the GUI isn't very intuitive.

Comment: Its features outweigh that! I agree though, but it does work well.

Comment: just beeing curious: How did you place this nice screen shot into your answer?

Comment: You can do print screen, or in Windows 7 - use the snipping tool. Save it to anywhere then find a descent image host such as tinypic.com and upload... then when you have the address, click the image button and paste the link! Sounds harder than it is.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it seems not to be possible to do an on-the-fly copy using Windows 7 built-in programs.

I looked around a bit and have found a nice and easy to operate tool called **[InfraRecorder](http://infrarecorder.org)**.

[image]

It has the additional advantage that it is also available as a native 64-bit application which matches perfertly well with the Windows 7 64-bit OS I am using.